# How to add files/folders to .gitignore in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

I try to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA. I have a project that uses Git and I want to quickly add files to *.gitignore* file. In Eclipse I can right click on a file/directory and choose '*Add to .gitignore*'.

Is there anything like this in IntelliJ IDEA or I have to edit the file manually?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125239) regarding this, please vote if you agree ;)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

IntelliJ has no option to click on a file and choose "*Add to .gitignore*" like Eclipse has.

The quickest way to add a file or folder to *.gitignore* without typos is:

1. Right-click on the file in the project browser and choose "*Copy Path*" (or use the keyboard shortcut that is displayed there).
2. Open the *.gitignore* file in your project, and paste.
3. Adjust the pasted line so that it is relative to the location of the *.gitignore* file.

**Additional info**: There is a [*.ignore*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=idea) **plugin** available for IntelliJ which adds a "Add to .gitignore" item to the popup menu when you right-click a file. It works like a charm.

Comment: Actually, using the menu item "Copy Reference" is closer to what you want to copy-paste. (and thank you for the tip)

Comment: I've added even better info: There is a plugin that can do this for you.

Comment: + for mentioning the plugin

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125239) regarding this, please vote if you agree ;)

Comment: nice one on the plugin - I was using Tortoise Git to to the same from the windows explorer

Answer (score 51):

Intellij had `.ignore` plugin to support this.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=idea

After you install the plugin, you right click on the project and select `new` -> `.ignore file` -> `.gitignore file (Git)`
[image]

Then, select the type of project you have to generate a template and click `Generate`.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can create file .gitignore and then Idea will suggest you install plugin

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy until I found your post :-)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the screen print showing the options to ignore the file or folder after the installation of the .ignore plugin. The generated file name would be .gitignore
[image]

Comment: How is this answer to a 4-year-old question helpful when there are already several working solutions to this question, all of which are a few years old? When posting answers to questions, make sure your answer is helpful and relevant.

Comment: The screen print is just an addition to the answers listed above. Sure, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using intelliJ 15 community edition and I'm able to right click a file and select 'add to .gitignore'

Comment: I'm using version 2022 and the option was not available. I installed the plugin but you can't ignore the file from commit panel

Answer (score 1):

right click on the project create a file with name .ignore, then you can see that file opened.

at the right top of the file you can see install plugins or else you can install using plugins(plugin name -  **.ignore**).

Now when ever you give a right click on the file or project you can see the option call add to .ignore